# How to establish connection to another pc using wired Lan on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, lan, wired

I have tried changing inet address on eth0 after attaching to wired Lan. I manage to ping myself.But when I ping another PC, i get destination host unreachable message.

Please help. I have tried so many command.But still failed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily an ubuntu-only problem.

When you are establishing a connection between two PC, you need some specific equipment.  First off, if you are just using an ethernet cable, you need to make sure it's a Crossover cable.  This is different from a normal patch cable, and if you purchase it in the store, the packaging should say Crossover Cable.  If you connect with a crossover cable, you should then be able to communicate.

If you don't have a crossover cable, then you need some network hardware to sit in between the two machines.  Either a hub or switch should do, and what's even better is to get a "home router" which includes a switch and routing and DHCP software built in, making network management even easier.

Comment: You also have to ensure you are using valid IP addresses which are in the same network and can therefore communicate with each other.